# Interfacing ds18b20 with raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

i have a raspberry pi connected with two ds18b20 temperature sensor.
-sensor1 is fixed on the outside of my garage (distance 20m from raspberry pi)
-sensor2 is just connected in a breadboard near the raspberry pi.
Everything is working well.

I decided to add sensor3 located outside and from 20m from the raspberry pi.

Now when i type :
cd /sys/bus/w1/devices

if find this:
c0-40a000061005  c2-246056869800  c2-247056869000  d0-008000001000  w1_bus_master1

instead of :
28-.....
28-.....
28-.....

each sensor ref should be start with 28-.....

what is happening with my sensors?
If unplugged the sensor1, then everything is well

if i unplug the sensor3 and let only sensor1 and sensor2 everything is well.

Which modification do we have to do  when sensor are located far from the raspberry pi?

thank you

Comment: This question appears to belong on [Raspberry Pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You should search for something like "Guidelines for Reliable Long Line 1-Wire Networks".

Comment: are these sensors powered from the pi or a separate 5V? You might have too big of a voltage drop having all three on the same bus

Comment: i resolved this problem by adding 10k resistor near the sensor and now it looks good, but the temp curve looks weird like square instead of curve.

Comment: You will need a pull-up resistor across the main voltage when tying two of those together any time. It is surprising that you did not get the error with two (in my experience). As for the curve, show it and we might be able to give you better feedback.

Answer (score 0):

That means that the 3rd sensor doesn't have a 4.7kOhm or 10kOhm resistor between VCC and the OUT wire (black/red one if you have 4wire DS18B20).
Just connect that resistor and it will work , I had the same problem . I spent weeks to find such an easy solution. And if you get the same code after you connected the resistor , that means you didn't connected it properly.Hope will help you